# VMWare for test IIS Server

Tags: iis, vmware-server

I'm wondering if anyone can help. I'd like to run IIS on a VMWare server, but I'd like to be able to access the IIS server on it using a browser on the PC.

Can anyone tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you set up a host connection for the virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

I tested VM with Apache on Ubuntu using browser from my WinXP so this is possible.
Simple check IP address you got from VMware (for example use ipconfig). I set "Ehternet: host only" in device configuration.

Answer (score 0):

To access IIS from the network you need to make port forwarding for VirtualBox.
Please follow these instructions: http://www.thecrumb.com/2009/12/08/alternate-virtualbox-port-forwarding-method/